# Cut video after certain time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam, video-encoding, video-capture

So I have found out how to cut a video at a specific time frame by using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 00:00:30.0 -c copy -t 00:00:10.0 output.wmv
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 30 -c copy -t 10 output.wmv
```

So this works but it works on a video file output.wmv, How could I do this in real time? Basically I want a camera to be running and recording 24/7 and when I click a button it will save the last 30 seconds. So what that means is anything older then 30 seconds I no longer need. So what I want to do is essentially cut off any frames that are older then 30 seconds, from an input stream (webcam) so that I do not fill up the HDD in one day.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to do this, but you could record to a different file every few minutes and delete older files? Truncating a file from the start is probably difficult?

Comment: 2 possible issues, 1) is it possible that frames will be lost while the recording stream starts / stops? 2) Say I cut every 1 minute, if someone presses the button at 1:15, I would only have a 1 minute clip and a 15 second clip.

Comment: 2) But if you only need 30 seconds, 1 minute and 15 seconds should be enough? 1) you could try overlapping recordings, but that may not work.

Comment: Sorry if post was confusing, what I mean is, the camera will be running 24/7. Then for demonstration sake you cute every 1 minute, then say at 8:00:15 you click the button, you would only have 15 seconds of film (in the foremost clip) or 1 minute in the previous clip

Comment: Oh, so you just need the time length of the video file and then cut the last 'n' seconds as needed?

Answer (score 1):

http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/ffmpeg-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-part-v/

"5. Record a stream endlessly rotating target file"

That handles your circular buffer.

You might have to do a little experimenting to see what works for you to get the previous 30 seconds. There are a number of ways to do that so it'll be up to the implementer.

Comment: You should provide actual context instead of just a link. What if the link vanishes? See [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).